# Decoding HTML Special Character

Tags: php, html, csv

I want to export some of my data into CSV with the help of PHP. The code is working correctly but some of the keywords that I want to export was in some other unicode which I had saved in database using

```
urlencode('אריה דרעי');
```

This saved the unicode in this format in database:

```
%26%231488%3B%26%231512%3B%26%231497%3B%26%231492%3B+%26%231491%3B%26%231512%3B%26%231506%3B%26%231497%3B
```

The main problem here is when I display it in an HTML page it displays fine but when I try to export it in CSV it shows the same texts.

I tried to use following function

```
url_decode('%26%231488%3B%26%231512%3B%26%231497%3B%26%231492%3B+%26%231491%3B%26%231512%3B%26%231506%3B%26%231497%3B');
```

But it again genereated special characters as

```
&#1488;&#1512;&#1497;&#1492; &#1491;&#1512;&#1506;&#1497;
```

Then I tried it to further decode using

```
 htmlspecialchars_decode();
```

But still it shows אריה דרעי in the CSV files.

I hope I make sense.

Comment: The reverse of urlencode() is urldecode() - if you're not getting back to your original data then your description is incomplete.

Comment: `But still it shows אריה דרעי in the CSV files.` -- doesn't that mean it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try using htmlspecialchars() instead of url_encode()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php
and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: Still this is the result: &#1488;&#1512;&#1497;&#1492; &#1491;&#1512;&#1506;&#1497;