# Decoding Special Character

Tags: javascript, html, special-characters

I am making an api call which sometimes returns strings with special character codes in the string, something like `adi&oacute;s` is being returned, and I need to display to my user as `adiós` instead. I have tried several combinations of `escape`/`unescape` `encodeURI`/`decodeURI` on their own and together, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get this to work! My teammates were able to get them to display using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but I know there has to be a better way? What might I be missing on this? The only other thing I can think would be to write a regex for it, but the problem is I don't know all of the characters that I might get back from the api to know what to write in the regex. Any help would be appreciated!
I have read a few posts, one of which was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707132/decoding-html-special-character) one, and another that suggested setting utf-8 encoding in the index.html file, but the problem is that is already set. We are using react for our project if it makes any difference!

This is the code where I am setting the text

```js
setHelperText(
  // todo: fix this to display dangerously set inner HTML so it handles regex
  `Sorry, wrong answer! The correct answer was: ${currentQuestion.correctAnswer}`
);
```

Where currentQuestion is from the api request. The api is https://opentdb.com/api

Comment: Sharing some code would really help here for us to help

Comment: adiós has spanish accent mark, do you have this problem with all words with accent mark?

Comment: Posting some code relevant to the problem would help us greatly. Anyway,  I tried to decode it using decodeURI and was able to get the expected result.

Comment: @Dominik I just added a bit of code. Sorry I didn't include it to begin with. It is hard to pick out what pieces exactly might be useful in a big project, but that is the relevant parts I am working with.

Comment: @sonEtLumiere I am having trouble with accents, apostrophes etc.

Comment: @Tushar were you about to decode it with decodeURI with the entire word and not just the one character?

Comment: do you have the correct encoding in your html ? <meta charset="utf-8" />

Comment: @sonEtLumiere Yes, my html encoding is set exactly like that

Comment: @Randy_E, yes, I was able to decode the entire word with decodeURI and got **adiós**.   You can have a look at this snippet https://codepen.io/tushar2004/pen/GRoQWmE?editors=1010

Comment: @Tushar that works because of `.innerHTML`, so there is no need for decodeURI ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the HTML entities for you. The main reason why `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is considered *dangerous* is if you're displaying user input back to the end-user as this can enable XSS attacks. You can also consider using [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) or another sanitizing library if you're wanting to reflect user input back to the user.

Here is an example using a DOMParser to parse the HTML string:

```js
const parseEntities = txt => new DOMParser().parseFromString(txt, 'text/html').body.innerText;

const App = () => {
  const txt = 'adi&oacute;s';
  return <p>{parseEntities(txt)}</p>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps

```js
function htmlEntities(str) {
      return String(str).replace('&ntilde;', 'ñ')
                        .replace('&Ntilde;', 'Ñ')
                        .replace('&amp;', '&')
                        .replace('&Ntilde;', 'Ñ')
                        .replace('&ntilde;', 'ñ')
                        .replace('&Ntilde;', 'Ñ')
                        .replace('&Agrave;', 'À')
                        .replace('&Aacute;', 'Á')  
                        .replace('&Acirc;','Â')
                        .replace('&Atilde;','Ã')   
                        .replace('&Auml;','Ä')
                        .replace('&Aring;','Å')
                        .replace('&AElig;','Æ')
                        .replace('&Ccedil;','Ç')
                        .replace('&Egrave;','È')
                        .replace('&Eacute;','É')
                        .replace('&Ecirc;', 'Ê')
                        .replace('&Euml;','Ë')
                        .replace(   '&Igrave;', 'Ì')
                        .replace('&Iacute;', 'Í'    )
                        .replace('&Icirc;', 'Î' )
                        .replace(   '&Iuml;', 'Ï')
                        .replace(   '&ETH;', 'Ð')
                        .replace(   '&Ntilde;', 'Ñ')
                        .replace(   '&Ograve;', 'Ò')
                        .replace(   '&Oacute;', 'Ó')
                        .replace('&Ocirc;', 'Ô' )
                        .replace(   '&Otilde;', 'Õ')
                        .replace('&Ouml;', 'Ö'  )
                        .replace('&Oslash;', 'Ø'    )
                        .replace(   '&Ugrave;' ,'Ù')
                        .replace(   '&Uacute;', 'Ú')
                        .replace(   '&Ucirc;', 'Û')
                        .replace(   '&Uuml;', 'Ü')
                        .replace(   '&Yacute;', 'Ý')
                        .replace('&THORN;', 'Þ' )
                        .replace(   '&szlig;', 'ß')
                        .replace(   '&agrave;', 'à')
                        .replace(   '&aacute;', 'á')
                        .replace(   '&acirc;', 'â')
                        .replace(   '&atilde;', 'ã')
                        .replace('&auml;', 'ä'  )
                        .replace(   '&aring;', 'å')
                        .replace(   '&aelig;', 'æ')
                        .replace(   '&ccedil;', 'ç')
                        .replace('&egrave;', 'è'    )
                        .replace('&eacute;', 'é'    )
                        .replace('&ecirc;', 'ê' )
                        .replace('&euml;', 'ë'  )
                        .replace(   '&igrave;', 'ì')
                        .replace('&iacute;', 'í'    )
                        .replace('&icirc;', 'î' )
                        .replace('&iuml;', 'ï'  )
                        .replace('&eth;', 'ð'   )
                        .replace(   '&ntilde;', 'ñ')
                        .replace('&ograve;','ò')
                        .replace('&oacute;','ó')
                        .replace('&ocirc;','ô')
                        .replace('&otilde;','õ')
                        .replace('&ouml;','ö')
                        .replace('&oslash;','ø')
                        .replace('&ugrave;','ù')
                        .replace('&uacute;','ú')
                        .replace('&ucirc;','û')
                        .replace('&uuml;' , 'ü')   
                        .replace('&yacute;', 'ý')  
                        .replace('&thorn;', 'þ')
                        .replace('&yuml;', 'ÿ');
}

console.log(htmlEntities("adi&oacute;s"));
```

Comment: lol thanks! That is what I didn't want to have to do